# Fill in values with the most recent non null with Snowflake SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

This is my table with values

```
id    category   

A     Apple
A     NULL     
A     Apple
B     NULL      
B     Pear
B     Pear
B     Peach
B     NULL
B     NULL
C     NULL
C     NULL
C     Apple
```

This is what I want my table to be

```
id    category   

A     Apple
A     Apple     
A     Apple
B     NULL      
B     Pear
B     Pear
B     Peach
B     Peach
B     Peach
C     NULL
C     NULL
C     Apple
```

These are the rules that I want to apply;

- If category is null, then fill it in with the most recent category (for that id)
- If there is no value for category above for that id, then remain null

We can imagine that there's a third column called date and that's what the data is sorted on

I tried to use `first_value()` but I just got nulls for the category column

I'm using SQL on a Snowflake instance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You seem to want `lag(. . . ignore nulls)`.  Just one thing:  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets (technically multisets).  You need a column to specify the ordering.

So:

```
select t.*,
       coalesce(lag(category ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by <ordering col>) as imputed_category
from t;
```

Actually, it turns out that `last_value()` does this without needing the `coalesce()`:

```
select t.*,
       last_value(category ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by <ordering col>) as imputed_category
from t;
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and first value?

Comment: @Cauder . . . `first_value()` gets the first value that appears.  `lag()` and `last_value()` get the most recent row -- based on some ordering column of course.

Comment: Do I need to add a window frame on last value so that it gets the most recent value up to the current row? As opposed to including values in following rows

Comment: I thought first_value or last_value would work, too, but the ID = B means LAG() with the coalesce is the way to go.

Comment: This is what I went with:      `coalesce(category, last_value(category ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by date rows between unbounded preceding and current row))`

Comment: Is the coalesce redundant?

Comment: @Cauder . . . I think so.  `LAST_VALUE()` will take the value from the current row if it is not `NULL`.  Also, the `ROWS` window frame is redundant -- well, unless you have duplicates in the `ORDER BY` column.

Answer (score 7):

For those finding this years later, not sure how the non-reproducible example was selected.

Here is functioning Snowflake SQL code that shows the problem of other answers at scale (specifically, back to back nulls!!)

The question specifically states:

> If category is null, then fill it in with the most recent category (for that id)

last_value() and first_value() are not the same as (unfortunately non-existent) prev_value().

```
SELECT
    column1 as token,
    column2 as hr, 
    column3 as price, 
    lag(column3) ignore nulls over (partition by column1 order by column2) as lag_price,
-- you want to coalesce itself and null removed lags!!
    coalesce(column3, lag(column3) IGNORE NULLS over (partition by column1 order by column2)) as correct_price,

-- commented out because it does not work, not enough arguments to coalesce!!
-- coalesce(lag(category ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by <ordering col>) as imputed_category,
-- coalesce(lag(column3 ignore nulls) over (partition by column1 order by column2) as imputed_price,

    LAST_VALUE(column3 IGNORE NULLS) OVER (PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column2) AS last_price
FROM VALUES
    ('usd', 1, 10), ('usd',2, NULL), ('usd',3, NULL), 
    ('usd',4, NULL), ('usd',5, 20),
    ('eth', 1, 20), ('eth', 2, 21), 
    ('eth', 3, NULL), ('eth', 4, 10), 
('eth', 5, NULL), ('eth', 6, NULL);
```

Notice that CORRECT_PRICE is what meets the definition of question, whereas last_value() only looks correct incidentally because this data was limited.

Image included:
[image: Correct Query that returns the most recent value for nulls as requested by asker]

Answer (score 3):

Syntax is:

> FIRST_VALUE(  ) [ { IGNORE | RESPECT } NULLS ]
> OVER ( [ PARTITION BY  ] ORDER BY   [ { ASC | DESC } ] [ <window_frame> ] )

Default is `IGNORE NULLS`, but if you specify `IGNORE NULLS` you won't get them.

Here is the documentation link, if you need it:

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/first_value.html

Comment: Would this work for the ID = B in the example table? I wonder whether it would pick pear instead of peach

Comment: Ah, no, you have a more interesting result than I originally though, and I didn't look into the detail there.  That's a more complicated query, since you are looking for the last value that isn't a null in a series, rather than the first value overall in the series.  Use `LAG()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
with t as (
select ord,id,category from (values
(0,'A','Apple'),
(1,'A',NULL),
(2,'A','Apple'),
(3,'A','Orange'),
(4,'A',NULL),
(5,'A','Apple'),
(1,'B',NULL),
(2,'B','Pear'),
(3,'B','Pear'),
(4,'B','Peach'),
(5,'B',NULL),
(6,'B',NULL),
(7,'B','Orange'),
(8,'B',NULL),
(1,'C',NULL),
(2,'C',NULL),
(3,'C','Apple'),
(4,'C',NULL),
(5,'C','Pear'),
(6,'C',NULL) ) as t (ord,id,category)
)

select
    *
    ,lag(category) ignore nulls over(partition by ID order by ord) as lagged
    ,coalesce(category,lagged)
    ,last_value(category ignore nulls) over(partition by ID order by ord) as lv
from t
```

Gordons first answer is the correct one, you need lag with coalesce. last_value will return the last non null value of the id partition. In this more robust example you can see how each works.